# revert git back initial condition

Tags: xcode, git, github

I was trying to add a repository to my xcode project, but instead of adding my project files to the repository, git removed my entire project. I think I can use 'git revert' option to revert the changes, but how do I know where to revert to?

Answer (score 2):

Get the list of commits using 
`git log`  this will list out all the commits with its hash, to revert the commit use

```
git revert (part of the hash)
```

for example if the commit hash is adghgd356484fghfbht76, do

```
git revert adghgd3564
```

Comment: I know I can use git revert, as stated in my question, but how do I find the right commit? i.e. what goed here: git revert /what goes here/

Answer (score 0):

If you have not pushed your changes to remote, you can run `git reset --hard` which will undo all your local changes and you will loose those changes from the history as well

Comment: The problem is that the first commit is an empty folder. So I am looking for the data before xcode decided to whipe the original repo and create the empty one from github instead. I'll consider the project lost.